# How to access the H2 console for Spring Boot without Spring Web?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, h2

H2 is a part of the Spring Boot app and spring-data-JPA is the only Spring dependency. In the application.yml file, I have

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enable: true
```

I try localhost:8080/h2-console, localhost:8082/, localhost:8082/h2-console and none of them work. I also try to set the path

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enable: true
      path: /h2-console
```

but none of 8080/h2-console, localhost:8082/h2-console works.

How to access the console if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

The H2 console is implemented as a Jakarta Servlet. You'll always need a servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty to run it.

A Spring Boot application that depends **only** on Spring Data JPA does not have an embedded servlet container. Thus, it cannot host the H2 console.

You need to add Spring Web if you want the H2 console. Spring Boot will then auto-configure Tomcat as servlet container.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That is what I thought. The app is built with Spring Boot and JavaFX as it is a desktop app, but not a web app.